# translating string matches to a vector of binary elements

Tags: r, regex, string, character, tidyverse

I appreciate your assistance with either suggesting a package or a base R solution to the following problem (Thank you in advance.)

Imagine I have a vector of character elements from a `statistical_function` (*below*). If I provide the name of two character elements (e.g., `provided = c("high", "aware")`), then I want a mechanism to produce the following binary vector for me: `desired_vector = c(0,1,1,0,1)`.

**Length:** This `desired_vector` has the same length as the number of elements in the output of the statistical function MINUS the element named `intrcpt`. Thus, in this case, `desired_vector` will have `5` elements.

**Elements A:** For each element in the `statistical_function`'s output that doesn't contain `:` (e.g., `"weekhigh"`) but does contain one of the `provided` vector's elements (`"high"`) my desired vector should be `1`.

**Elements B:** For each element in the statistical function's output that does contain `:` (e.g., `"weekhigh:testeraware"`) and does contain BOTH of the `provided` vector's elements (`"high"` & `"aware"`) my desired vector should be `1`.

Else all remaining elements in the `desired_vector` should be `0`. Is this possible to achieve in R?

In the below example, 1st element of `desired_vector` is `0` because `intrcpt` aside, `weekssome` doesn't contain either `"high"` or `"aware"`, 2nd element is `1` because `weekshigh` has `"high"`, 3rd element is `1` because `"testeraware"` contains `"aware"`, 4th element is `0` because `"weekssome:testeraware"` doesn't contain BOTH `"high"` and `"aware"`, and 5th element is `1` because it does contain BOTH `"high"` and `"aware"`.

```
statistical_function = c("intrcpt","weekssome","weekshigh",            
"testeraware","weekssome:testeraware","weekshigh:testeraware")

# [1] "intrcpt"               "weekssome"             "weekshigh"            
# [4] "testeraware"           "weekssome:testeraware" "weekshigh:testeraware"

provided_vector = c("high", "aware")

desired_vector = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the approach below is what you are looking for. I wasn't sure if you'd always want to drop the first element. To have some control over what is being dropped, I added the `drop` argument. It takes either the number of the element(s) to drop, or a string, which with the name of the element to drop. It defaults to `drop = "intrcpt"`, which drops the intercept.

```r
# the input vector containing the coefficient names
statistical_function  <- c("intrcpt",
                           "weekssome",
                           "weekshigh",
                           "testeraware",
                           "weekssome:testeraware",
                           "weekshigh:testeraware")

# the input vector containg the search pattern
provided_vector = c("high", "aware")

# a function which matches both
test_input <- function(in_func, in_vec, drop = "intrcpt") {
  
  if(!is.null(drop)) {
    if(is.numeric(drop)) {
      in_func <- in_func[-drop]
    } else if (is.character(drop)) {
      in_func <- in_func[in_func != drop]
    }
  }
  
  inp <- strsplit(in_func, ":")
  
  pat <- paste(in_vec, collapse = "|")
  
  vapply(inp,
         FUN = function(x) all(grepl(pat, x)), 
         FUN.VALUE = numeric(1L))
}

# this does not drop the intercept, so this is not the desired result
test_input(statistical_function, provided_vector)
#> [1] 0 1 1 0 1

# these calls drop the "intrcpt" or the first element
test_input(statistical_function, provided_vector, drop = "intrcpt")
#> [1] 0 1 1 0 1
test_input(statistical_function, provided_vector, drop = 1)
#> [1] 0 1 1 0 1

# test: still working
test_input(statistical_function[-1], provided_vector)
#> [1] 0 1 1 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If the intercept is always writtin in the same way `intrcpt` then we can minimalize the function above and remove the `drop` argument:

```
test_input <- function(in_func, in_vec) {
  
  inp <- in_func[in_func != "intrcpt"]
  inp <- strsplit(inp, ":")
  
  pat <- paste(in_vec, collapse = "|")
  
  vapply(inp,
         FUN = function(x) all(grepl(pat, x)), 
         FUN.VALUE = numeric(1L))
}
```

Comment: Dear Tim, first of all thank you for reading thru my long post and even offering a solution. I can't be more grateful. If there ever will be an element named `"intrcpt"`, it will be the first element. But I noticed there is a bug. If you drop `"intrcpt"` in `statistical_function = c("weekssome","weekshigh",            
"testeraware","weekssome:testeraware","weekshigh:testeraware")`, then your function returns `1 1 0 1` which means `"weekssome"` contains `"high"` of course that's not correct.

Comment: Thank you Tim, this works better. Essentially, we want the function to ignore `"intrcpt"` if one exists in `statistical_function` .

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
+(
  abs(
    grepl(":", statistical_function) -
      rowSums(
        sapply(provided_vector, grepl, statistical_function)
      )
  ) == 1)[
  statistical_function != "intrcpt"
]
```

which gives

```
[1] 0 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: @rnorouzian Maybe you can try `unique(trimws(strsplit(aa, "[*+:]")[[1]]))`

Comment: @rnorouzian What about `grep("\\D", unique(trimws(strsplit(aa, "[*+:]")[[1]])), value = TRUE)`?

Comment: @rnorouzian If `aa` has more than 1 string, you should use `grep("\\D", unique(trimws(unlist(strsplit(aa, "[*+:]")))), value = TRUE)`